# laravel 5.3.16 not including bootstraps functionality?

Tags: css, laravel, authentication, view

Don't know what i'm doing wrong this time at installing Auth in laravel 5.3.16

The installation of laravel and Auth are both working but the layout of the Auth views miss the bootstrap includement. So all content is shifted to the left and there is nog CSS included.

The difference in looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIrsm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcnqw.jpg

What can I do to fix the missing CSS?

Comment: Check in the browser console if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the command php "artisan make:auth" does not automaticly include the bootstrap and jQuery libs.

This should be included manualy.